# Check Whether Particular query from multiple query is affected or not

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, rows-affected

Let Suppose i have Following code which updates two different table

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $updateq = $conn->query("UPDATE `tbl1` SET `field1`= '$field1'");

    $updater = $conn->query("UPDATE `tbl2` SET field2 ='$field2'");

    //Here I want to check if first update query
    //is affected any row or not
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0){
        ....
    }

}
```

*So is it possible to check whether first query is updated any row or not ?*

Comment: $sql = "sql statement"; mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error()); if(mysql_affected_rows() || mysql_affected_rows() == 0){ // no error }else{ // error }

Answer (score 0):

IN mysql

> - ROW_COUNT() returns the number of rows changed, deleted, or inserted    by the last statement if it was an UPDATE, DELETE, or
>     INSERT. For    other statements, the value may not be meaningful.

so,

```
UPDATE `tbl1` SET `field1`= '$field1'
SET @countRow =  ROW_COUNT();
if (@countRow>0) then
UPDATE `tbl2` SET field2 ='$field2'
end if;
```

you have to integrate this in php as it is purely mysql syntax